# Movie with spider aliens?

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, horror

I remember watching this weird/freaky movie when I was a kid (maybe like 7-8, so perhaps around 7-ish years ago, give or take). I don’t remember a whole lot but from what I *do* remember is that it was about these people that had troubles with their ship and got stranded on the moon.

They explored as best they could and at one point found an old Russian spaceship that had been abandoned. There were some dead guys in it.
Later on I vividly remember an alien that looked like a spider or a tarantula crawling under this guy's skin and eventually crawling into his helmet. (Those events might have been vice versa.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like this could be the movie Apollo 18. The movie was released in 2011, which matches your timeline and the details you provided match some of the descriptions from the summary on [IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1772240/plotsummary).

*They explored as best they could and at one point found an old Russian spaceship that had been abandoned/there were some dead guys in it*

> During further exploration they discover footprints that lead them to a Soviet LK lander nearby, finding it functional but blood-stained

*Later on I vividly remember an alien that looked like a spider or a tarantula crawling under this guys skin, and eventually crawling into his helmet*

> Walker feels something moving inside his spacesuit and helmet and is horrified as a spider-like creature crawls across the inside of his helmet